# Can we style multiple html tag by one id selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Happy new year everyone. I have an important question. 
Can we do style to multiple tags in `html` by one id selector?
When I studied `CSS` I learned that the `ID` selector is used to select the tag in one time, but I am surprised when I gave same id for multiple tags, the 
style is applied on all tags having that id.
This my simple code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #link{color:red}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="" id="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" id="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" id="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" id="link">RED</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Can any one explain this case?
thanks

Comment: Id is for one element you can't set the same id for multiple element

Comment: it works but you should not use it (it won't work with jQuery for example). ID should be unique even if it works well on many elements

Comment: @M0ns1f the issue is that you CAN do it, but you should not do it ;)

Comment: You can, you also can do other things wrong, but you shouldn't as the result is likely to be unexpected.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah i know but we can't make same id in one Mysql Table, same concept

Comment: @M0ns1f not exactly the same :) in MySql there is constraint to oblige you to use different ID, like in C langague where you are obliged to end with  `;` or to not use same name for variable,etc ... but here you are free to do it and it can work fine, but the rules/specification tells you to avoid such behavior as ID are meant to be unique. And as you can see it's working fine in his code

Comment: I know that.But i was want an scientific explain for this case all answer is true bu i liked for two answer one for  @atb00ker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although that works, this is not valid html, because the document is supposed to have unique, non-duplicated ids. If you run that code through some validator, it will give you an error.

If you want same styles applied to multiple elements, you need to look at css classes.

Answer (score 2):

[HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) & [HTML 5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) specification says ID must be document-wide unique.
In short:
HTML will never throw an error but it is important that you use `ID` only once in a page, it is meant to be unique.

This is important for various kinds of readers.
Use `class` if you want to apply same style to multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `ID` Selector must **UNIQUE**.

*It doesn't allow using duplicate `ID` Selector.*
It is not STANDARD

If you want to set the same `ID` for multiple elements, You should better use the `class`.

For example,

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #link{color:red}
  .link{
    color: red
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Your code...
   <a href="" id="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" id="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" id="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" id="link">RED</a>
   -->
   <a href="" class="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" class="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" class="link">RED</a>
   <a href="" class="link">RED</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `It doesn't allow using duplicate ID Selector` the *it* refers to what/who ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm sorry. I'm not good at English, So I think I used the inappropriate word. `It doesn't allow using duplicated ID Selector` means `It's not standard`. That's it.